# When $x^n+y^n=(x+y)Q_n$ then $Q_n$ only has prime factors $p=1 \mod n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Total amateur here, playing with some math... With prime $n$, $\{x,y,x+y,n\}$ all mutual coprime and $x^n+y^n=(x+y)Q_n$, then I think I can prove that $Q_n$ only has prime factors $p=1\mod n$. Some questions:

1. Is it known?
2. Is there a simple way to show this? It takes me about 2 pages...
3. Is it related to some specific field of research?
4. Is it somehow useful?

Comment: Say $n=45, x=2, y=11$.  Then $x+y=13$ and $Q_n$ has prime factors including $19, 31, $ and $61\not\equiv1\bmod45$

Comment: @J.W. Tanner: you're right! I looked back into my proof and saw I forgot in my question here to state that $n$ is prime. I checked millions of combinations of $\{x,y,n\}$ in WxMaxima to check for a quick counterexample but found none.

Comment: Fermat's little theorem says $a^{q-1} \equiv 1 \pmod q$, so $x^q + y^q \equiv x + y \pmod q$. If it's invertible, dividing by that gives $1 \equiv Q_q \pmod q$.

Comment: @rain1: but that only shows that $Q_n=1(\mod n)$ and not that every prime factor of $Q_n$ has the form $p=1 (\mod n)$?

Comment: yeah I am not sure how to get the prime factors = 1.

Comment: $x^n+y^n\equiv0\pmod p\implies (\frac xy)^n+1\equiv 0 \pmod p\implies (\frac xy)^{2n}-1\equiv0 \pmod p\implies 2n|p-1\implies p\equiv1\pmod{2n}\implies p\equiv1\pmod n$

Comment: About 4: you can prove (using this fact) that there are infinitely many primes $q\equiv 1\pmod p$ (special case of Dirichlet's theorem). You only need to check that there are infinitely many primes which divide $\frac{x^p+y^p}{x+y}$ for some integer $x$ and $y$ (you can even set $y=-1$).

Comment: @J.W. Tanner: It looks as if you proof that every prime factor of $x^n+y^n$ must be of the form $p=1(\mod n)$. But $x+y$ divides $x^n+y^n$ and I can choose any combination of $x$ and $y$ for which $x+y$ has prime factors unequal to $1(\mod n)$. So I think there something wrong in your proof.

Comment: really $(\frac xy)^{2n}\equiv1\pmod p \implies$ $ (\frac xy)^{\gcd(2n,p-1)}\equiv1\pmod p$; $\gcd(2n,p-1)=2n$ or $2$ ; in the former case, $2n|p-1$, and in the latter case $p|x\pm y$

Comment: Ah, now I see. I needed that additional clarification. Much simpler than my approach where I first proved that for the given restrictions $\gcd(Q_m,Q_n)=1$ with $m$ and $n$ odd integers and $\gcd(m,n)=1$ and I then got my result with one additional step. Thanks for the education.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address question 2., here is a way to show your result.

Say $p$ is an odd prime dividing $x^n+y^n,$ with $n$ prime and $x$, $y$, $x+y$, and $n$ mutually prime.

(Note:  if $n=2$, then $x, y, $  $x+y$, and $n$ cannot be mutually prime; thus, $n$ must be odd.)

Then $x^n\equiv -y^n\pmod p$; i.e., $(xy^{-1})^n\equiv-1\pmod p,$ so $(xy^{-1})^{2n}\equiv1\pmod p$.

We also have $(xy^{-1})^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$, so $(xy^{-1})^{\gcd(2n,p-1)}\equiv1\pmod p.$

Now $\gcd(2n,p-1)=2$ or $2n.$

If $\gcd(2n,p-1)=2$, then $(xy^{-1})^2\equiv1\pmod p$,
so $x\equiv\pm y\pmod p$,

which must mean $x\equiv-y\pmod p $ since $x^n\equiv-y^n\pmod p$, so $p|x+y$.

So if $p\nmid x+y$, then $\gcd(2n,p-1)=2n$, which means  $2n|p-1$, so $n|p-1$;

i.e., $p\equiv1\pmod n$.